# Understanding simple functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$, let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be a step function. That is, there exists a partition $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ and constants $c_1,...,c_n\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=c_i$ for all $x\in(x_{i-1},x_i)$ and each $i=1,...,n$. Then $f$ is equal to the following simple function
$$\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\chi_{(x_{i-1},x_i)}+\sum_{j=0}^nf(x_j)\chi_{{\{x_j}\}}.$$

I don't understand how can we express function $f$ as given above?

Answer (score 1):

If $B=\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}\subseteq[a,b]$ and $A=[a,b]-B$ then the expression can be recognized as:$$f\chi_A+f\chi_B$$and we have:$$f\chi_A+f\chi_B=f(\chi_A+\chi_B)=f$$